# will finally block work without try block in python?

Tags: python, exception, try-except, finally

If I do not specify any try and except block in python, will **finally** work in the program?

or I can use **finally** only with a try block.

```
if condition:
   print('something')
else:
   print('something else')
finally:
   print('I will always run')
```

Comment: According to me, finally block should always execute at the end of the program.

Please help me correct my Understanding!

Comment: Did you try to run the code yourself?

Comment: You can only use finally in conjunction with a try-block.

Answer (score 2):

No, it won't work outside a `try` block, because `finally` is part of the `try` statement, as evident from [Python's grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html):

```
try_stmt: ('try' ':' suite
           ((except_clause ':' suite)+
            ['else' ':' suite]
            ['finally' ':' suite] |
           'finally' ':' suite))
```

So the `finally` keyword can occur only within the `try_stmt` production, which captures `try` statements.

Answer (score 1):

No, `finally` is only used with `try`. Its purpose is to run some code after the `try` and/or any `except` block, *whether or not* the code in the `try` block threw an exception. The `finally` block is executed immediately after the `try` or `except` block, not delayed until the end of the program. See the [official docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions) for a more thorough explanation.

`finally` is useful if you need to clean up some resources before continuing. For example:

```py
f = open('myfile.txt')
try:
    f.write('blabla')  # This might raise an exception, for example if the disk is full
finally:
    f.close() # Close the file whether the write failed or not.
```

Without `finally` we'd have to repeat the cleanup statement, like this:

```py
f = open('myfile.txt')
try:
    f.write('blabla')
except:
    f.close()
    raise
f.close()
```

**In Python, it is almost always better to use a `with` block instead of `try`/`finally`.**

Finally, in your example, you might as well write:

```py
if condition:
   print('something')
else:
   print('something else')
print('I will always run')
```